# Dynamic Date for Param

Tags: reporting-services, mdx, ssrs-2016

I am trying to get the param to automatically fill todays date.  I am using query designer and MDX with this.

```
StrToMember(“[Date].[Calendar Year].&[“+Format(now(), “yyyy”)+”]”)
```

The above is what I have tried to get to work but it is not.

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[LY MTD New and Up] AS 
([Measures].[Parallel Last Year MTD Quantity],[Performance Groups Name].&[149]) 

SELECT NON EMPTY { 
[Measures].[Profit], 
[Measures].[MTD Profit], 
[Measures].[Weekly Trending Profit], 
[Measures].[Parallel Last Week Profit], 
[Measures].[Parallel Last Month MTD Profit], 
[Measures].[Parallel Last Year MTD Profit], 
[Measures].[LY MTD New and Up] } 

ON COLUMNS, NON EMPTY { 
([Locations and Employees].[Store Name].ALLMEMBERS ) } 

DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_VALUE, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME 

ON ROWS FROM ( 
SELECT ( [Date].[Calendar].[Day].[2018-08-18]  ) 

ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@LocationsandEmployees, CONSTRAINED) ) 
ON COLUMNS FROM [Super])) CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS
```

This works

[image]

This is not working

[image]

I have also tried

```
 [Date].[Day].&[now()]
```

```
StrToMember('[DHC].[DHC].&[' + Format(Now(),'dd/MM/yyyy') + ']')
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not getting date in the right format, if 18-Sep-19 works, then you could try with `'dd-MMM-yy'` format - that should give you exactly the format you need

Comment: Changing it to that format still is not working for me.  I am using this expression in the custom field of the parameter. Does that matter?

Comment: [Date].[Day].&[Format(Now(),'dd-MMM-yy')
] Returns no rows

Comment: Maybe you can try version without ampersand also: [Date].[Day].[Format(Now(),'dd-MMM-yy')] . Also, when you try to select [Date].[Day].[18-Sep-19] on 0 from yourcube do you get something?